# How to document javascript callback parameters with Sphinx?

Tags: javascript, python-sphinx

I've been using the Sphinx documentation generator to document my javascript framework, however i'm not sure how i should go about documenting the parameters my callback functions get, for example

```
.. js:function:: execute(event, callback)

  :param object event: The event object 
  :param function callback: the handler 
  :returns: a Promise
```

In the previous example callback is called with a `request` and `reply` parameter, however looking at the sphinx documentation for the javascript domain does not specify how i should go about documenting this.

What's the correct way?

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html?highlight=js%20domain#the-javascript-domain